# Google Sheets / Excel: How to find most common value in a list with formula depending on dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This formula in the sheet works:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(B2:B10,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10)),COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10),0)))
```

The issue is connecting it to the dropdown menu. It only returns the first mentioned Sales Person of a day. It should return the Sales Person with their name appearing the most for a given day depending on which day in the dropdown menu is selected.

Example of issue:

[image: Sheet Issue]

The desired output should be Bill for 1/1/2021, Bob for 1/2/2021, and Ben for 1/3/2021.

Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your E2 formula:

`=QUERY(SORTN(QUERY(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=D2),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col1) ''"),1,1,2,0),"Select Col1")`

`FILTER` isolates only the names that fall on the D2 date.

The innermost `QUERY` aggregates those by count.

`SORTN` sorts them highest to lowest and returns only the highest, but with a tie mode setting that will return all matches if there is a tie.

The outermost `QUERY` returns the name only (eliminating the no-longer-needed count).

Comment: Both your formula and Harun24HR's formula work great! Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got the help you needed. Just keep in mind that, if you want to show all matches in case of a tie for the given day, you'll need the formula I provided above.

Comment: Erik, your formula works wonders! There is much forethought in it I recognize now. The formula solves issues before I knew I had them. Thank you again! By the way, what is a good resource for getting to this level of sophistication with formulas?

Comment: I say quite often that anyone who knows anything essentially learned it the same way: from scratch and one piece at a time. No one is born an expert. And there is no one-stop shop (even college education) that teaches all there is to know about a thing. I myself am a mentor, author and public speaker with degrees in Psychology. But I'm now an "expert" (who's still learning) in information design, web design, graphic design, several languages, singing and vocal coaching, composing, editing, etc.—all of which I learned on my own, "from scratch and one piece at a time." You can too.

Comment: As for resources, forums like this are a great place to "spy on" questions and solutions: to try your hand at how you'd solve them, fail (or partially succeed, or succeed clunkily), tear apart the solutions of others until you understand the parts and the whole, etc. You could literally memorize every single function listed in the "official documentation" from Google, and still not be good. A spreadsheet is a canvas, and functions are paintbrushes and paint. Those things alone don't make art. Art is made by people practicing, experimenting and using things in new ways.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(B2:B10&"@"&COUNTIFS(A2:A10,$D$2,B2:B10,B2:B10),"@"),2,FALSE),1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is perfect! By any chance, would you know how to display two or more Sales Persons' names if there was a tie? For example, if Bill and Bob's name came up 2 times for 1/4/2021.